# Unity - Tilt a spaceship when turning to the left or the right

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Currently I have got a spaceship which flies around a planet. It looks like this

[image]

and I use this code

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float currentMovementSpeed = 30;
    private float rotationSpeed = 80;
    private Rigidbody rigid;

    private void Start()
    {
        rigid = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // move the spaceship
        rigid.MovePosition(rigid.position + transform.TransformDirection(new Vector3(0, 0, 1)) * currentMovementSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        // rotate the shaceship by pressing A or D
        transform.Rotate(0, Input.GetAxis(StringCollection.INPUT_HORIZONTAL) * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
    }
}
```

So when I press A I want to tip the ship to the left

[image]

and when pressing D I want to tip ship to the right

[image]

Does someone know how to do that?

Comment: You can check in Update if A or D is down and then apply your rotate function.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of this:

```
transform.Rotate(0, Input.GetAxis(StringCollection.INPUT_HORIZONTAL) * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
```

You should use something like this:

```
 rigidbody.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (0.0f, 0.0f, rigidbody.velocity.x * -tilt);
```

Here is a sample where it is used:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[System.Serializable]
public class Boundary
{
    public float xMin, xMax, zMin, zMax;
}

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public float tilt;
    public Boundary boundary;

    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);
        rigidbody.velocity = movement * speed;

        rigidbody.position = new Vector3 
        (
            Mathf.Clamp (rigidbody.position.x, boundary.xMin, boundary.xMax), 
            0.0f, 
            Mathf.Clamp (rigidbody.position.z, boundary.zMin, boundary.zMax)
        );

        rigidbody.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (0.0f, 0.0f, rigidbody.velocity.x * -tilt);
    }
}
```

You may be interested in watching the following tutorial, since it is similar to what you are trying to create:

https://unity3d.com/es/earn/tutorials/projects/space-shooter/moving-the-player?playlist=17147

Answer (score 0):

You could also check out this asset - all the code is commented and it's super smooth - helped me a lot.

Basically, it has a pretty versatile script to do LERP based cam following of the ship. This is kind of like a normal Smooth Follow, except you get it in full 3D, so the ship can go fully upside down, etc. The controls are easily changeable, which I did myself, but the default is that the ship is continually moving and you use arrow keys for pitch/yaw.

Here's the main idea - you have a childed camera target object and the camera uses LERPing to follow it - gives a super interesting effect for access/deceleration:

```
// lerp the camera back to its correct position
    _cam.transform.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(_cam.transform.localPosition, _camTarget.transform.localPosition, 1f - CameraLag);
    _cam.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(_cam.transform.localRotation, _camTarget.transform.localRotation, 1f - CameraLag);
```

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/3d/vehicles/space/low-poly-space-ship-ultra-smooth-360-controller-111640